# Newsletter in magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

In magento 2.1.0 I try to create newsletter but I am getting following error in my log:

```
[2016-12-23 12:41:56] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. 
[] []
[2016-12-23 12:42:43] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively.
 [] []
[2016-12-23 12:42:43] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. 
[] []
[2016-12-23 12:42:43] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively.
```

Comment: use this reference: http://blog.belvg.com/newsletters-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: Order confirmation mail also not working. please help..